# Remove brackets and quotations from list

Tags: python

`filter_col` list below gives me a list like this:

```
['RP026_IP_1_S9_L001_R1_001']
['RP026_IP_2_S10_L001_R1_001']
['RP026_IP_3_S11_L001_R1_001']
['RP026_IP_4_S12_L001_R1_001']
```

How can I remove the brackets and make it more like this:

```
RP026_IP_1_S9_L001_R1_001
RP026_IP_2_S10_L001_R1_001
RP026_IP_3_S11_L001_R1_001
RP026_IP_4_S12_L001_R1_001
```

This is how I made the list:

```
 treated_sample = ["RP026_IP_1_S9_L001_R1_001",
                          "RP026_IP_2_S10_L001_R1_001",
                          "RP026_IP_3_S11_L001_R1_001",
                          "RP026_IP_4_S12_L001_R1_001"]

for i in treated_sample:

    filter_col.append([col for col in df if col.startswith(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

for example if it's in a variable name **a**

you can do :

```
a.replace("['", "").replace("']")
```